# Mobile detected and alert to use desktop

Tags: javascript, mobile

Hello I'm building a website with xml, javascript and css. I want to give an alert to users who are accessing my site via any mobile browser to use a Desktop browser for a better experience. For this, I just want to let them scroll through my index page and them stop them to access any other pages of my website through mobile devices.

Can somenody give me hints or some info/docs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to detect a mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)

Comment: Thank you @Not A Bot Yes, about the device detection it is perfect. But there is no info about how can I prevent mobile user browsing my website.

Comment: Create a subdomain like **mobile.yourdomain.com** and if you detect that user is on the mobile device, send the user to **mobile** domain and in that just create an index.html file having text **"Please use desktop browser"**

Comment: Great!!!! Thank you for your help! 